# Which scriptures say that Tulsi leaves should not be chewed?

Tags: belief, tulasi

It is a belief amongst many that Tulsi should not be chewed.

Some say that Tulsi is associated with Vishnu so one must not chew it.

So where does it say Tulsi should not be chewed? Does it have scriptural basis?

Comment: It is false because tulasi leaves are added in teertham in temples. Where did you hear that there is that belief?

Comment: Throughout the internet. http://www.sciencebehindindianculture.in/why-should-tulsi-not-be-chewed-with-teeth-2/ , https://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/why-is-it-forbidden-to-chew-tulsi-leaves , https://food.ndtv.com/food-drinks/why-are-we-often-told-not-to-chew-tulsi-leaves-1735329 . Just google "Why Tulsi should not be chewed" I found so many. Also many people and Pundits also say so.